# How to access JSON request body of POST/PUT Request in Apache Camel/CXF REST webservice

Tags: java, json, rest, cxf, apache-camel

I am trying to pass a JSON request body to a REST Webservice which is made using CXFRS in my Apache Camel application.

I want to access the request JSON passed in my Processor.

**REST URL:**

```
http://localhost:8181/mywebservice/Hello/name/{request_param}
```

Though i am posting a JSON in request body, still in my processor `exchange.getIn().getBody()` always return the `{request_param}` not the Request JSON.

My REST webservice is as follows:

```
@Path("/name/")
@Consumes({"application/json" ,"application/xml"})
public class HelloRest {
    @POST
    @Path("/{name}")
    public TestPojo sayHi(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return new TestPojo(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Server part:

```
    @POST
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String add(MappingUser newUser){
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(newUser.getNickname(), newUser.getPassword());
    boolean ret = myDB.addUser(userEntity);

    //sends the return value (primitive type) as plain text over network
    return String.valueOf(ret);
}
```

Client part:

```
 public boolean addUser(User user){
    WebResource resource = client.resource(url).path("/");

    String response = resource
            //type of response
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            //type of request
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            //method
            .post(String.class, user);

    return Boolean.valueOf(response);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on that.